# How to symbolically (not in words) express that an angle measure is in degrees or radians?

Tags: notation, angle

How can an ALGEBRAIC angle measurement be explicitly expressed in degrees or radians? You can see my attempt below, But this doesn't look right for some reason, even if I change "deg" to degree symbol. What do you think? Can you suggest anything?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't look right, because it's not on the right! ;) The units should be attached to the numerical values, on the right side of the equation, not on the left side.

Comment: You could move the units to the left side by dividing: $$\frac{Y}{\text{rad}}=0.6$$ $$\frac{Y}{1^\circ}\approx36.87$$ But that would probably confuse people.

Comment: By the way, where is $36.87^\circ$ coming from? Since $\pi\,\text{rad}=180^\circ$, we have $0.6\,\text{rad}=0.6\times180^\circ/\pi\approx34.38^\circ$.

Comment: @mr_e_man, interesting remark you've made. I didn't give it a thought. 0.6 comes from the ratio of the sides, which is 3/5 for sine, so arcsin(0.6) would be around 36.87 degrees. But I thought 3/5 was the measure in radians, no?

Comment: No. A radian angle measure is not a ratio of triangle edge lengths; it's a ratio of circle arc length to circle radius. In most contexts, it's a "type error" to take $\arcsin(0.6\,\text{rad})$; the input should be a number, not an angle. (Occasionally we don't make the distinction, and say $1\,\text{rad}=1$, as in Karl's answer.) But if your triangle is a $3,4,5$ right triangle, then the $0.6$ is actually a ratio of edge lengths, and the angle should be $$Y=\arcsin(0.6)\approx36.87^\circ\approx0.6435\,\text{rad}$$ $$Y\neq0.6\,\text{rad}$$

Comment: It is true that when the triangle's height $h$ is small compared to the hypotenuse $r$, then $\arcsin(h/r)\approx(h/r)\,\text{rad}$. The circular arc is just slightly longer than the triangle's edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People are asking for more context on what you're trying to do because it seems like you might be misunderstanding something.

Angles are like lengths. If $x$ is equal to 1 meter, then $x$ is equal to 100 cm. The expressions "$x$", "1 meter", and "100 cm" all denote the same thing, which is a *length*, not a number. You could use the phrase "$x$ in cm" to refer to the plain real number 100 (or the expression $\frac x{\text{$1$ cm}}$, i.e. the ratio of the length $x$ to the length $1$ cm), but then your results are tied to a choice of unit.

It's usually clearer to work directly with lengths rather than numbers. For example, if $d$ is my dog's height and $c$ is my cat's height, then "$d>c+c$" doesn't require units to make sense. We're adding and comparing lengths, not numbers.

Similarly, with angles, you can write things like $\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\frac12$, which is unambiguous without declaring units for the angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$, because the input to $\cos$ is (conceptually) an angle, not a number. We only need units when writing literal numeric quantities.

One thing that confuses the issue slightly is that plain numbers are also considered angles, with the conversion $1=\text{$1$ rad}$.

Comment: If I define sine as a ratio of sides of a right triangle, I need the input to be in degrees. That's what I wanted to explicitly stress: sin(m∠Y), where m∠Y is in degrees. But I don't want to use the words "where m∠Y is in degrees." Instead, I want m∠Y to somehow "signal" to the reader that it's the measurement of angle "Y" in degrees, maybe by appending a degree sign or something (that's what I'm trying to find out).

Comment: @bp2017 The shape of the right triangle depends on the angle itself, not on the units you might choose when writing that angle as a number. How do you think "$\sin(m\angle Y)$" could be misinterpreted?

Comment: If you know in advance that m∠Y must be in degrees because that's the only input for sin, it won't be misinterpreted. What I'm trying to do here is to state this simple requirement (almost everyone knows about) explicitly, and I never thought it would turn out to be this hard.

Comment: But $\sin(\angle Y)$ is defined as a ratio of side lengths of a right triangle with interior angle congruent to the angle $Y$. There are no units involved in this definition, because the concept of congruent angles is not unit-dependent. Most software defines `sin` to take its input in radians, though.

Comment: After giving it some thought, I now realize what confused me: when you divide the opposite side of an angle by the hypotenuse, you have a measurement in radians, because the hypotenuse is the radius. But when we talk about radians, people expect the measurement of an arc, not the measurement of a side.

Comment: The ratio of two lengths is not an angle! That's why we need the trig functions - to convert between angles and these ratios.

Comment: Yes, that's what I pointed out in my previous comment.

Comment: By the way, in your answer, when you say that "you can write things like cos(α+β) . . . without declaring units for the angles," it is true only for Greek letters, not for Latin letters (I have Latin "Y").

Comment: Where are you getting that? It seems like you're still operating on some misconceptions.

Answer (score 1):

$$m \angle Y = 0.6 = 0.6 \text{ rad} \approx 36.87 \text{ deg} = 36.87^\circ$$

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian#Unit_symbol

Comment: What I meant was this: How do you express m∠Y in radians or degrees explicitly, without relying on those numbers that follow.

Comment: Because I need to use algebraic m∠Y for that, not the actual numbers (to which, of course, I can append a degree sign or "rad" unit).

Comment: The reader has to know that m∠Y is in radians or angles (explicitly stated), but how much exactly degrees or radians, he doesn't know (because I don't provide that, although in my question there were numbers after the equals sign).

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do.  What content are you creating, and who is your audience?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to write m∠Y so that it would be understandable by the reader that the measurement "m" is in radians (or, alternatively, in degrees, but EXPLICITLY). I can't figure out where I should put "rad" or "∘": after "Y" or after "m." My audience is anyone who expects a legal mathematics notation from me, not some made up stuff (that's why I'm seeking help here, to standardize).

Comment: Is this part of a research paper, a presentation slide, a homework set to give to students?  I think some context is needed.  What prose will appear before and after the figure?

Comment: Your quest for standardization on this is in vain, I'm sorry to say. That's because a) there is no standard and b) standardization is a matter of consensus, and you're not going to achieve that with regards to the global maths community via this site. With regards to your diagram, the standard notation would be to simply refer to the angle $Y$ itself, i.e. $Y=0.6 \rad$ or $Y=36.87 \deg$. Why do you want more notation when you've already given it a symbol?

Comment: @H.sapiensrex, I am not trying to standardize my notation so that everyone uses it; on the contrary, I want my notation to adhere to the standard notation. By the way, why do you have backslash between 0.6 and "rad"?

Comment: Ah, I see. Well as I said, the closest thing to a standard on this is referring to the angle by the symbol you use to denote it in the first place, be it $Y, \theta, \alpha, \psi$ or whatever. And the backslash was a mistake lol